# SQL merge 2 lines of response

Tags: sql, sqlite

Hello I'm new to SQL language and i want to get all of my antibodies but when i use this query:

```
SELECT id, a.name antibodyName, c.name colorName FROM Antibodies a JOIN AssignedColors c
              ON id = antiId WHERE colorId IS NOT NULL
```

and i get this response:

```
[
  { id: 1, antibodyName: 'antibody 1', colorName: 'red' },
  { id: 2, antibodyName: 'antibody 2', colorName: 'red' },
  { id: 2, antibodyName: 'antibody 2', colorName: 'yellow' }
]
```

how can i change it to something like this?

```
[
  { id: 1, antibodyName: 'antibody 1', colorName: 'red' },
  { id: 2, antibodyName: 'antibody 2', colorName: 'red, yellow' },
]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want aggregation:

```
SELECT a.id, a.name as antibodyName, GROUP_CONCAT(c.name) as colorNames
FROM Antibodies a JOIN
     AssignedColors c
     ON a.id = c.antiId
WHERE colorId IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY a.id, a.name;
```

Comment: is it possible to get this result in SQL?
[
  { id: 1, antibodyName: 'antibody 1', colorName: [{name: 'red'}] },
  { id: 2, antibodyName: 'antibody 2', colorName: [{name: 'red'}, {name: 'blue'} ]},
]

Comment: As a string or using a SQLite extension?  If you want JSON, I would suggest asking a new question.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63669392/how-to-get-array-of-json-from-sql-select/63669907#63669907 I appreciate if you answer TNX