# How to get Array of JSON from SQL select

Tags: sql, sqlite, node-sqlite3

I want to get an array of objects inside of my SQL select.

```
SELECT id, a.name antibodyName, c.name colorName, c.location colorLocation 
FROM Antibodies a 
JOIN AssignedColors c ON id = antiId 
WHERE colorId IS NOT NULL
```

and I get this response:

```
[
  { id: 1, antibodyName: 'antibody 1', colorName: 'red', colorLocation: 'A5/C3' },
  { id: 2, antibodyName: 'antibody 2', colorName: 'red', colorLocation: 'C3/A1' },
  { id: 2, antibodyName: 'antibody 2', colorName: 'yellow', colorLocation: 'E4/F2' }
]
```

is it possible to get something like this?

```
[
  { id: 1, antibodyName: 'antibody 1', colors: [{name: 'red, location: 'A5/C3'}] },
  { id: 2, antibodyName: 'antibody 2', colors: [{name: 'red, location: 'C3/A1'}, {name: 'yellow', location: 'E4/F2'}] },
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a bit rusty, but try this:

```
SELECT
a.id AS 'Id',
a.Name AS 'antibodyName',
c.Name AS 'name',
c.location AS 'location'
FROM Antibodies a
LEFT JOIN AssignedColors c ON c.id = a.Id
FOR JSON AUTO;
```

UPDATE: the above is not for SQLite. For SQLite you should checkout the json1 extension here: https://www.sqlite.org/json1.html

ANOTHER UPDATE:
it can be done without the JSON extention...

```
SELECT
a.id AS 'id',
a.Name AS 'antibodyName',
(SELECT '[' || GROUP_CONCAT('{name:"' || Name || '", location:"' || location || '"}') ||']'
 FROM AssignedColors
 WHERE c.id=Id) AS colors
 FROM Antibodies a
 LEFT JOIN AssignedColors c ON c.id = a.id
 GROUP BY a.id
```

theres a small issue here: the colors column/node is treated as a string and not an array... this is normal as sqlite doesnt support a column of type array. some parsing will need to be done to convert from string to array...

Comment: are you this works in sqlite? because it gives me undefiend

Comment: Hi @mj checkout the update to the answer... You right, it’s not going to work on sqlite

Comment: I read the question and somehow skipped reading over the tags...

Answer (score 1):

Use json_build_object and array_agg.

```
WITH foobar AS ( 
    SELECT id, a.name antibodyName, c.name colorName, c.location colorLocation 
    FROM Antibodies a JOIN AssignedColors c
    ON id = antiId WHERE colorId IS NOT NULL
    )
SELECT 
     json_build_object('data',array_agg(json_build_object('id', id, 'antibodyName', antibodyName, 'colorName', colorName, 'colorLocation', colorLocation))
FROM 
    foobar
```

Comment: are you this works in sqlite? because it gives me undefiend

Comment: No this would work for postgresql. But you can modify it using this documentation.
https://www.sqlite.org/json1.html